# (JAVA) JDBC Template несколько переменных через IN в select

Tags: java, jdbc, шаблоны, jdbctemplate

Не получается передать значение в переменную in в select, для подключения к базе использую JDBC Template.

Пример запроса:

```
    public List<Clnt> getClnt(String codeStr , String clnt){
    List<Cities> clntList;
    String SQL = "select * from clnt where CODE in (:codeStr ) and CLNT_ID in (:clnt)"
    
    try {
        citiesList = jdbcTemplate.query(SQL,
            new Object[]{codeStr,clnt},
            new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Clnt.class));
    } catch (Exception err) {
        logger.error(err);
    }
        return clntList ;
    }
```

Если передавать в переменные по одному параметру codeStr=123asd и clnt=123 запрос отрабатывает , но если в запрос передаются несколько значений codeStr=123asd,456fgh и clnt=123,321 или в какию то переменную один параметр а в другой 2, то запрос не отрабатывает.

Comment: Насколько я знаю такой трюк поддерживает только NamedJdbcTemplate. В вашем случае запрос надо составлять динамически, вставляя нужные строковык значения в IN, что не есть хорошо с точки зрения SQL инъекции. И я бы рекомендовал не надеяться на магию Спринга, а двигаться от базовых решений к сложным. В конце концов preparedStatement и resultSet никто не отменял.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант с использованием `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` потребует преобразования строк со значениями `"v1, v2, vN"` в список `[v1, v2, vN]` и создания мапы параметров [`MapSqlParameterSource`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.springframework/spring-jdbc/4.3.7.RELEASE/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/MapSqlParameterSource.html) в качестве реализации [`SqlParameterSource`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.springframework/spring-jdbc/4.3.7.RELEASE/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/SqlParameterSource.html):

```java
private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate npTemplate;

public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.npTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}

public List<Clnt> getClnt(String codes, String clnt) {
    SqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource(Map.of(
        "codes", Arrays.asList(codes.split(",\\s*")),
        "clnt",  Arrays.stream(clnt.split(",\\s*"))
                       .map(Integer::valueOf)
                       .collect(Collectors.toList())
    ));
    
    try {
        return npTemplate.query(
            "select * from clnt where CODE in (:codes) and CLNT_ID in (:clnt)",
            params,
            new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Clnt.class));
    } catch (Exception err) {
        logger.error(err);
        throw new RuntimeException("Query failed", err);
    }
}
```